# duScrollTop not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have the following code, but the scrolling does not work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-scroll/1.0.2/angular-scroll.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 120vh;">EXAMPLE</div>
  
  <footer>
    <button ng-click="scrollToTop()">To the top!</button>
  </footer>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', ['duScroll']).
  controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document){

    $scope.scrollToTop = function() {
      $document.duScrollTop();
    };

  }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The method `duScrollTop()` does not work for me.

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical term. Your HTML is invalid by putting the script elements before the doctype.

Comment: can you help edit it? I'm new

Comment: Instead of "not working", explain the problem in more detail. What behavior are you expecting and what is happening? Also, check if you are getting any error messages, and add those as well.

Comment: Your [Spanish question](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105129) seems to have more detail as well, which would be nice to include in this question too, although that question also does not explain what is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You `$scope.scrollToTop` method is declared within `MyCtrl`, so you have to use [`ngController` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) to allow using this method with [`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick);

2) Simply calling [`scrollTop()` will return current scroll position](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll#user-content-angularelement-scroll-api); to scroll to specified position you have to pass arguments to this method:

> `.scrollTop|scrollLeft( top [, duration [, easing ] ] )`
>
> Scrolls to specified position in either axis, with optional animation.

Here is a working example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['duScroll']).
controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document){
  $scope.scrollToTop = function() {
    $document.duScrollTop(0);
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 120vh;">EXAMPLE</div>
  <footer>
    <button ng-click="scrollToTop()">To the top!</button>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-scroll/1.0.2/angular-scroll.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```